# Data modeling diagram notation, what is this?

Tags: database-design

What does this type of notation mean in a logical data model? There is three tables in this diagram and x inside "half moon". So, what is this "x inside half moon". I could not find this e.g. from different diagramming conventions mentioned in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model).

```
             _________
            |_________|
            |         |
            |_________|
                 |
                 |  
               -----
              /__x__\
                 |
          _______|_________
    _____|_____        ____|______
   |___________|      |___________|
   |           |      |           |
   |           |      |           |
   |___________|      |___________|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the 2 child entities are exclusive subtypes of the parent super type.

This is "Information Engineering" notation

For example, see ERWin notes (at the bottom) http://www.isqa.unomaha.edu/wolcott/tutorials/erwin/erwin.html

Answer (score 1):

There is already a correct answer, but I thought the following might be useful to future visitors.

In ER modeling, this pattern is known as "specialization/generalization".   In languages like Java, "subtypes" might be known as "subclasses".

When you move from ER modeling to SQL (relational) table design, you will likely be at a loss for a good way to represent this pattern.  Introductory material about database design often does not include this pattern, even though it occurs over and over again.

Fortunately, the is a well understood design technique that's useful here.  If you visit the [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) tag, and click on "learn more", you'll get an overview of one useful technique and links to two related techniques.